# Laravel session not working on server

Tags: php, session, laravel, server

On my local environment, laravel 4 sessions works perfectly but on my server not so.
If I do :

```
Session::put("user_id", 1);
echo Session::get("user_id");
```

it show : `1`
But if I do :

```
Session::put("user_id", 1);
return Redirect::to("something");
```

where I have :

```
echo Session::get("user_id");
```

it return undefined variable.

on my session.php I've got :

```
...
'driver' => 'file',
'domain' => "",
...
```

and after a `Session::put()`, it create a file on `storage/sessions` but after, the `session::get()` is not available.

Need help please !!

Comment: Check for session exist if (Session::has('user_id')) {
  echo Session::get('user_id');
}else{echo 'session not exist';}

Comment: I checked it and it return 'session not exist' but I don't unnderstand why my session is missing.

Comment: i had similiar problems with laravel 3. what i did there is, i had to manually call `Session::save()` after `Session::put`. one more thing, if you are using `dd()` in your code, `Session::save()` doesn't get called even if you call `Session::put()` before `dd()`. Lots of probability here.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to call 'Session::save()', and it create one another file in my 'storage/sessions' folder, but still not working, I tried every drivers : 'cookies/database/file' but still not working, I think there is a key thing, I didn't notice.

Comment: The domain must be your project domain, or .domain.com to subdomains.